# /subscribers/{imsi}/enable_termination(disable_termination)の動作について

Tags: soracom

/subscribers/{imsi}/enable_termination(または、disable_termination)を実行したときに登録済みのSIMのIMSIを指定して実行するとResponse Code 400で処理に失敗してしまいます。パラメータが足りないのでしょうか？
※コマンドの実行は、https://dev.soracom.io/jp/docs/api/#/ から行っております。

Response Body:

```
{
  "code": "SEM0003",
  "message": "Bad request: Invalid Json"
}
```

また、登録されていないIMSIを指定しても同じ結果が返ってきました。

Comment: /subscribers/{imsi}/set_expiry_time
/subscribers/{imsi}/unset_expiry_time
こちらのAPIも Response Code:400で返ってきました。

    {
      "code": "SEM0003",
      "message": "Bad request: Invalid Json"
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ご指摘ありがとうございます。

こちら、API リファレンスの Swagger の設定が誤っておりました。
すでに修正してデプロイ済みですので再度お試しいただけますでしょうか。

（ブラウザのキャッシュが残っている場合がありますので、もし動作しないようであればブラウザのキャッシュのクリアもお試しください）

Comment: ありがとうございました。動作HTTP Status Code: 200が返ってくるようになりました。